# R - sequence of continuous cases where end1 == start2

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, match

Take this dataset...

```
test <- data.frame(
    t1=c(2,3,5,6,7,10,10),
    t2=c(3,4,6,7,8,11,12),
    id=1:7
)
```

...which looks like this.
To clarify, each row is a previously identified link of two cases that have to stay bound together.

```
  t1 t2 id
1  2  3  1
2  3  4  2
3  5  6  3
4  6  7  4
5  7  8  5
6 10 11  6
7 10 12  7
```

I am hoping to identify the continuous sequences based on t2 == t1 recursively so that the links are:

```
link1 -  2-3,3-4
link2 -  5-6,6-7,7-8
link3 -  10-11
link4 -  10-12
```

The end result i'm looking for is this:

```
  t1 t2 id matchid
1  2  3  1       1
2  3  4  2       1
3  5  6  3       2
4  6  7  4       2
5  7  8  5       2
6 10 11  6       3
7 10 12  7       4
```

I have experimented with `match(test$t2,test$t1)` to get the initial links but am now getting stuck on how to continue the linking process.
My thoughts keep falling back to using a loop and that sounds like a terrible way to go.

Comment: a suggestion. why don't you offset t2 downwards by 1, then all the ones with same numbers for t1 and t2 would belong to the same id.

Comment: @RJ- see my clarification - the t1/t2 combinations in each row are tied together and can't be moved independently of one another.

Comment: i understand. the move is temporary to facilitate the checking. the idea is to offset, check and generate a new column to indicate if the t1 == t2. So say i use YES to indicate t1 == t2 and NO to indicate t1 != t2. After which i use run length encoding (rle) to determine the run length and use that to generate an increasing id based on the rle. After all that is done, the offset can be reversed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
test$matchid <- c(1, 1 + cumsum(tail(test$t1, -1) != head(test$t2, -1)))
```

Comment: That is flipping brilliant, but you're going to have to explain  it to a dunderhead like me.

Comment: hehe, just take it one step at a time. I suggest you start and type `tail(test$t1, -1)` to see what it returns, then `head(test$t2, -1)`, then compare them with `!=`, etc. You'll see it is not that difficult.

Comment: brilliant indeed! much better than i could think of.